# PHP Mini Offline WebServer?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, webserver, localhost

How can I make an offline webserver to test my scripts even when I'm not connected to the internet?

Is there any tutorial on the internet that can help me? Which programs do I have to download to make my "mini" server?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using? For Mac there's [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html), for Windows there's [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Add UNISERVER to the local servers list. It is really good.

Comment: I dunno why you would wanna use MAMP for Mac, seeing as iOS comes bundled with apache all you need do is enable it, and then setting up mysql/phpmyadmin with php isn't all that tough, couple quick lines in the terminal, then a couple quick changes to config files, and your done, a novice could have it up in an hour maybe even less as there are pleanty of examples that will just copy and paste the commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

WampServer is a Windows web development environment. It allows you to create web applications with Apache2, PHP and a MySQL database. Alongside, PhpMyAdmin allows you to manage easily your databases

Comment: once I install wamp i'll have my webserver with php and mysql?

Comment: yes exactly you will have apache, mysql and php all in one. It is really easy and usefull package.

Comment: error opening the program "Exception Exception in module wampmanager.exe af 000F15A0 Could not execute action: ."...

Comment: Try using 32 bit version of WAMP if you are trying to install 64 bit. this generally happens with 64 bit wamp.

Comment: Also if you didn't saw the warning, you need to install Visual C++ 2010 sp1 redistrbutable package. VC10 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe 32 bits : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328

Comment: yes, I already have them downloaded

Comment: downloaded 32 bit version and I'm still having the same problem ://

Comment: double check again you have both 32 bit wamp and visual c++ redistrubitables installed. this problem is because of them: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,71125,printview,page=1

Comment: k, I uninstalled everything and installed again, now it's working fine! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[XAMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/)

[Vertrigoserv](http://vertrigo.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

In general "yes". You just need to install http server + php + perhaps SQL on your local machine and set it up. If you are on windows, then there're bunch of ready-to-use packages like [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/), [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or other.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your answer. It is a perfectly valid and useful answer posted before any other. I agree, it is a "cowardy downvoter", one of those who gets his friends to upvote his answers while he downvotes other's. Something that seems to be happening in this site very often, unfortunately, although I am pretty new to it. I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried WAMP, I always used XAMPP and Vertrigo, but WAMP looks much easier to use and install!

Comment: Yes, its very simple and easy!

Comment: good, i'll download it later, thanks!